# How to send object to UITableViewCell at init or awakeFromNib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell, but I need to know something from an object in order to create different things at initialization point.

Here is my code to be more specific:

```
import UIKit
import TNCheckBoxGroup

class MenuOptionsCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!

    var checkboxData : AnyObject?
    var checkbox : TNCheckBoxGroup

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        checkboxData = TNCircularCheckBoxData()
        (checkboxData as! TNCircularCheckBoxData).borderColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 161/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        (checkboxData as! TNCircularCheckBoxData).circleColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 161/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1)
        (checkboxData as! TNCircularCheckBoxData).borderRadius = 18;
        (checkboxData as! TNCircularCheckBoxData).circleRadius = 14;

        checkbox = TNCheckBoxGroup(checkBoxData:[checkboxData!], style: TNCheckBoxLayoutVertical)
        checkbox.create()
        checkbox.position = CGPointMake(16, 16)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        addSubview(checkbox)

    }
}
```

Now, depending on some condition, I need the `checkboxData = TNCircularCheckBoxData()` to actually be `checkboxData = TNRectangularCheckBoxData()`

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the conditions? Can't you just [tableView reloadData]?

Comment: Please be more clear about your question. Do you want to set your `checkboxData` depending of what exactly? In what moment?

Comment: If you follow best practice, your cell objects will be re-used, probably for different rows/data, so you should adapt your cell's appearance either in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or if you want to keep the logic inside the cell class then via a setter method on the properties that affect appearance

Comment: To be more clear. When I open the ViewController that holds this table, I have a collection of items that need either a `TNCircularCheckBoxData` or a `TNRectangularCheckBoxData`. Those are view controllers that need to be added to the custom cell, so that's why I'm trying to add them at init. The simplest solution I can think of is to just create an extra custom cell, but I'm not sure that's optimal. 
I guess I could also just add both and hide/show the one needed on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but again, not sure if it's optimal. Hence, the question